# Arduino, Python, Serial and Unpacking Values: "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, unpack

This is my first question and I am relatively new to python, so kindly bear with me. Your guidance with this problem will be greatly appreciated!

I have a [pulse oximeter](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/pulse-and-oxygen-in-blood-sensor-spo2-ehealth-medical) which is used with a [particular Arduino shield](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/ehealth-sensor-shield-biometric-medical-arduino-raspberry-pi) to produce 2 simple signals: a pulse rate and an oxygen saturation content. See Arduino code:

```
#include <PinChangeInt.h>
#include <eHealth.h>

int cont = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);  
  eHealth.initPulsioximeter();

  //Attach the inttruptions for using the pulsioximeter.   
  PCintPort::attachInterrupt(6, readPulsioximeter, RISING);
}

void loop() {

  //BPM
  Serial.print(eHealth.getBPM());
  Serial.print(",");

  //SP02
  Serial.print(eHealth.getOxygenSaturation());  

  //NEW LINE
  Serial.print('\n');  
  delay(500);
}


//=========================================================================
void readPulsioximeter(){  

  cont ++;

  if (cont == 50) { //Get only of one 50 measures to reduce the latency
    eHealth.readPulsioximeter();  
    cont = 0;
  }
}
```

So the output into the serial monitor, in other words when pySerial readline() is called, the comma-delimited lines looks like:

```
65,95
67,96
67,95
70,94
```

Simple, right?

Well, I use a python program in combination with pySerial to read these values, assign them to a vector, print them on a graph in real time and save it to a .csv file.

For your reference, here is the program:

```
import serial
import time 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import csv

#time load
timestr = time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d")

#spacer
spacer = "_"

#user inputs name
name = raw_input('Enter full name:  ')
file_name = name + spacer + timestr
file_name_str = file_name+'.csv'

#change directory
path = '/home/pi/Desktop/pulseox/data'
os.chdir(path)
text_file = open(file_name, "w")
full_path = path + "/" + file_name_str

#check
print full_path

#establish serial connection with ACM0
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)

#establish vectors
thymeL = [ ]
bpmL = [ ]
sp02L = [ ]
array_data = thymeL, bpmL, sp02L


#declare time
thyme = 1

#establish plot values
#plt.axis([0,50,0,120])
plt.ion()
plt.title("Pulse [BPM] & SPo2 [%] v. Time [s]", fontsize = "16")
plt.xlabel("Time [s]", fontsize = "14")
plt.ylabel("Pulse (red) [BPM] & SPo2 (blue) [%]", fontsize = "14")

#print data to terminal, define time
while True:         
    data_in = ser.readline()
    bpm, sp02 = data_in.split(",")
    thyme = float(thyme)
    bpm = float(bpm)
    sp02 = float(sp02)
    print "Time [s]: %s" % (thyme)
    print "HR [BPM]: %s" % (bpm)
    print "SPO2 [%%]: %s" % (sp02)  
    print 

    thymeL.append(thyme)
    bpmL.append(bpm)
    sp02L.append(sp02)

    plt.scatter(thyme,bpm,color="red")
    plt.scatter(thyme,sp02,color="blue")
    plt.pause(0.1)
    time.sleep(0.05)

    thyme = thyme + 1

    with open(full_path, 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for t, b, s in zip(array_data[0], array_data[1], array_data[2]):
            writer.writerow([t, b, s])
```

**25% of the time everything works fine. But the other 75% of the time, randomly, the program will return the following error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last)L
    File "pulseox.py", line 74, in <module>
        bpm, sp02 = data_in.split(",")
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

**So ignore the rest of the program except for the following lines:**

```
data_in = ser.readline()
spm,sp02 = data_in.split(",")
```

If, in fact, the serial monitor is simply outputting 2 comma-separated values such as:

```
67, 95
71, 95
```

Then why is there an unpack error when the program is so simply instructed to unpack two variables and assign them to arrays? This is a problem that is occurring in another program of mine and I would like to get to the bottom of it! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the python code might read from the buffer when the Arduino has only printed partially. You are using 4 single prints for the Arduino and a `while True: data_in = ser.readline()` in the python code. So the following may happen:

```
void loop() {

  //BPM
  Serial.print(eHealth.getBPM());
  Serial.print(",");

  // *** At this point the python code may read what has been written so far, i.e. it receives an invalid data set and thus the ValueError. ***

  //SP02
  Serial.print(eHealth.getOxygenSaturation());  

  //NEW LINE
  Serial.print('\n');  
  delay(500);
}
```

You should first construct a string of the form `x,y\n` and then print this string using a *single* print. Then the python part either reads a data tuple or it doesn't but it won't read incomplete tuples leading to the unpacking failure.

So something like the following would do:

```
void loop() {

  char buffer[32];  // make sure buffer is large enough;
  sprintf(buffer, "%d,%d\n", eHealth.getBPM(), eHealth.getOxygenSaturation());
  Serial.print(buffer);
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, my intuition said that the python program is reading the arduino serial at an instance in which the line is not fully printed. After implementing your code and uploading it up to the Arduino, I still receive the same error on a frequent basis. Perhaps the buffer is not large enough?

Comment: This might be due to the implementation of `Serial.print`. Also I'm not aware of the detailed functionality of the C `printf` function. Maybe the print posts characters one by one to the stream but does not release the stream after finishing that (so it could be read before printing was fully done). Try modifiying your python code such that it reads from the stream until it encounters a `'\0'`. If multiple reads are necessary you can join parts to valid tuples. I'll try to update my anwer soon to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: I see what you mean and will attempt to modify my python code such that it does not execute a value unpack until the readline() function returns a full three values. However, do note that I am very new to python and any code suggestions would be of great assistance. I also apologize for the delay -- I was out of town for the weekend. Thanks!